# UIDocumentPickerViewController upload txt file from iCloud

Tags: swift, upload, icloud

```
@IBAction func iCloudPlayer(_ sender: Any) {
        var documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["public.txt"], in: UIDocumentPickerMode.import)
        documentPicker.delegate = self
        documentPicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.fullScreen
        self.present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: URL){
        if(controller.documentPickerMode == UIDocumentPickerMode.import){
            let content = openFile(path: url.path, UTF8: String.Encoding.utf8)
            titlePlayerContent.text = content
        }
    }
    func openFile(path:String, UTF8:String.Encoding = String.Encoding.utf8) -> String?{
        var error: NSError?
        return FileManager().fileExists(atPath: path) ? String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: UTF8, error: &error)! : nil

    }
```

> //Arguments labels '(contentsOfFile;,encoding;, erro:)' do not match any available overloads, **error on** ? String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: UTF8, error: &error)! : nil

any suggestion guys? how can i upload from iCloud, tutorials not working on Swift 3!

Comment: Have you looked at the Swift 3 documentation for `String` and its `init` methods?

Comment: And your issue has nothing to do with `UIDocumentPickerViewController` or iCloud.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your function body of `openFile`

```
func openFile(path:String, UTF8:String.Encoding = String.Encoding.utf8) -> String?{
        var error: NSError?
        return FileManager().fileExists(atPath: path) ? String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: UTF8, error: &error)! : nil

    }
```

With

```
func openFile(path:String, UTF8:String.Encoding = String.Encoding.utf8) -> String?{
        if FileManager().fileExists(atPath: path) {
            do {
                let string = try String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: .utf8)
                return string
            }catch let error as NSError{

                //Handle your error/exception here. I just returned a error as a string. You can return nil or something in this case too.
                return error.localizedDescription
            }
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
```

as per new changes in **Swift 3.x**

Comment: @ArkadijsArchieMakarenko If it works, Kindly accept as a tick!